# Failed to Send File to another computer on the same network using PHP

Tags: php, file, send

We're making a Foodlist site which has an Admin that has the privilege to "Add Food" and "Edit Food" which includes giving images. But all trials to send the food image to the actual computer we're going to use as a server has failed. It'd be weird to copy the image everytime we edit something or add something.

Our site requires us to simply send a file from our computer to another in their "xampp\htdocs\sitepage\images" folder. We're on the same network. Here's our code.

```
$my_file = 'C:\Users\ASUS\DownloadsMyFile.jpg';

/* New file name and path for this file */
$destination_file = '192.168.1.105/sitepage/images/INeedSomeRest.jpg';

/* Copy the file from source to server */
$copy = copy( $my_file, $destination_file );

/* Add notice for success/failure */
if( !$copy ) {
    echo "It didn't work.";
}
else{
    echo "WOOT! Successfully copied the file.";
}
```

It always gives us an error such that the browser says something like:
" failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ~our php file~ "

Is there something we're doing wrong? That being said, is there another way to send a file to another computer via PHP?
A Response will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your destination file variable is a relative path, there is nothing in there that would make it copy to another computer. Also, what's your use case for this? The question as it is makes me wonder why you need PHP at all.

Comment: Thank you for replying. So what should I do with the destination file variable then? o.o
Okay, so our entire site is actually more of a Foodlist for a simple school project and the Admin has the privilege to "Add Food" and "Edit Food" which includes adding images. But all trials to send the food image to the actual computer we're going to use as a server has failed. It'd be weird to copy the image everytime we edit something or add something. (adding this to the original question to avoid confussion)

Comment: Data transfer across a network does not exist by default. You need two programs that speak the same protocol and communicate together. If you use Windows you can maybe create a share (right click on a given folder) and use the appropriate path format: \\192.168.1.105\sharename`

Comment: @MarlXtianMonzonMarcera Do you mean you want the users to be able to upload an image of the food?

Comment: @JonStirling yes, that is exactly what we are trying to do.

Comment: @MarlXtianMonzonMarcera Then you're going down _completely_ the wrong route :P. Have a look through [file upload documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: @VolkerK oh is that so? Well there's another thing that wasn't taught to us. Be back in a jiffy.

Comment: Please check this out [copy file via smb protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638744/how-to-php-copy-across-smb-mount)

Comment: Generally speaking the PHP application would be a web application running on the *destination* machine and the users would connect to it (web browser) to submit the image via an HTML form... it *looks* like you're trying to do this arse-about-face in having a PHP application running locally on the client machine to push a file to a server? Seems to be completely the wrong approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I took the "copy" method of php all wrong. it seems it can only take a file from another server to your computer, and not the other way around. To the people who have the same problem as me, try to read about File Transfer Protocols. =) I appreciate all the replies. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

1) Try to use `$destination_file = 'http://192.168.1.105/sitepage/images/INeedSomeRest.jpg';` (note about **http://**)

2) Make sure that you CAN write to that resource (enough rights, shared properly, etc)

Comment: As a general rule, being able to push files through HTTP requires a verify specific set-up (such as a WebDAV server and client).